# laravel 4, model relations, get a list of a model with count of the related rows in the other model

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I have a model ( Journal )that is related to another model ( Toc), So each journal can have one or more TOC, I want to retrieve a list of journals with count of Tocs in each journal.

I created a code that retrieve a list of journals with a list of tocs in each journal then count tocs using PHP count function, but I think their may be a more efficient way rather than having to get the whole list which eats more memory.

Here is my code:

Model:

```
public function toc()
{

    return $this->  hasMany ( 'Toc', 'journal_id' ) ;

}
```

Controller:

```
$this->data['model'] = $this->model->with('toc')->get()  ;
```

Any help?  **Note: I'm using laravel 4**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Mutators` to set the value what you want, in your model Journal add:

```
protected $appends = array('numberOfTocs');
```

and the method to get this attribute:

```
public function getNumberOfTocsAttribute()
{
    return $this->toc()->count();
}
```

this way you have an additional attribute in your query corresponding to number of Toc.

[Here](https://softonsofa.com/tweaking-eloquent-relations-how-to-get-hasmany-relation-count-efficiently/) is other interesting implementation.

Comment: How can I use this additional attribute in my controller?
I can't follow the URL you provided,it shows and error while trying it.

Comment: if you debug your data['model'] you'll have the journal with additional attribute called numberOfToc

Comment: this is the link: https://softonsofa.com/tweaking-eloquent-relations-how-to-get-hasmany-relation-count-efficiently/